# Adding to cart: E_ERROR: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

We're seeing in new relic some reports of the below when users are adding items to the cart:

```
E_ERROR: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)
in Varien_Simplexml_Element::descend called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php (195)
in Varien_Simplexml_Element::descend called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php (153)
in Varien_Simplexml_Config::getNode called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php (671)
in Mage_Core_Model_Config::getNode called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php (298)
in Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data::getOldFieldMap called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php (129)
in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::_initOldFieldsMap called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Object.php (100)
in Varien_Object::__construct called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php (562)
in Varien_Data_Collection::getNewEmptyItem called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php (406)
in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getNewEmptyItem called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php (1053)
in Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::_loadEntities called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php (871)
in Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::load called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php (741)
in Varien_Data_Collection::getIterator called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php (1495)
in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addOptionsToResult called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php (182)
in Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_assignProducts called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php (139)
in Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_afterLoad called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php (581)
in Varien_Data_Collection_Db::load called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php (741)
in Varien_Data_Collection::getIterator called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php (1697)
in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::isVirtual called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php (489)
in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::getAllItems called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php (541)
in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::getAllNominalItems called at /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Nominal/RecurringAbstract.php (98)
```

Any ideas, please?

I have no idea what can be causing this and google is not turning up much!

Answer (score 1):

check in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php what is the value of $path passed to `return  parent::getNode($path);` at line 298.

plus check that the file app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php is the original one because on my magento 1.9.2.4 that call is on line 667 instead of 671